# How to make Android applications compatible with different screen resolutions?

Tags: android

How can we resize our application for different screens on different Android devices?

Comment: Deja Vu!?
There was a similar question asked here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946480/accoding-to-emulator-resolution-how-to-change-the-activityscreen-controls-size
Make sure you do a search before asking a question.

Answer (score 4):

If you want your layouts to work on different resolution screens your should be sizing them using `dip` as the unit.  For example:

```
android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
```

`dip` stands for Device Independent Pixel and using these in your layout means that Android will automatically scale your layout depending on which display the device running your application has.

You can read about these in the [*Supporting Multiple Screens* page in the Android Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence).  This document also has some other options for handling different displays but I think using `dip` is probably the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

yes, as Dave answered, using "dip" is the best way to go.

Also, some screens have different ratio of Heigth/Width, so using only "dip" will not be enough.
Then you have 2 options. If you always use Layouts like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc with "fill parent", you will be fine because the screen will grow.
But sometimes you set a fixed height on something, and if you deploy it on the droid (for example) it will look short because the droid has more height/width ratio than the G1/G2/etc
In that case you will need to set the height using code.

Comment: When you say "you will need to set the height using code", what do you mean exactly?  I ask because this is my main problem.  I have used DIP for everything, but the bottoms get chopped off on every smaller screen than Droid (hdpi, 854x480, long).

Answer (score 0):

Check the screen resolution in logcat using the following code

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

        height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

If the screen size is showing as 480x569 because of this only the screen may get chopped at the end. To solve this you have to change the minSDK version number in your manifest file.